# Orientation changes under modal view controllers

Tags: uiviewcontroller, device-orientation, orientation-changes

1. Present modal view
2. Change orientation
   2a. The modal view rotates
3. Dismiss the modal view

The parent view did not rotate and is now displaying wrong. Is there a fix?

(ALl of the subviews of the parent view are autoresized.)

Many thanks in advance!

Sam